# Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token:

Tags: java, aws-lambda, jackson, pojo

Hi Everyone i want to call my api from lambda but when i am passing the request i got this error "Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token"
This is the POJO but here only List aids is not deserializing when passing request from Lambda

```
@Data 
@Builder
@ToString
public class BulkFetchRequest {
 @JsonProperty("merchId")
 private String merchId;
 @JsonProperty("markId")
 private String markId;
 @JsonProperty("aids")
 private List<String> aids;
 }

This is my request format:

{
"merchId": "2077759361",
 "markId" : "44571",
 "aids": ["B096BK8GW", "B09B7S84X", "B07N7QPZD", "B09GG2LPL" , "B09M41GVR"]
}
```

Comment: Try initialising the List, like `private List<String> aids = new ArrayList();`

Comment: @shockwave in the POJO itself?